# Image loaded either if condition fails in ng-if in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In Angular Image is loaded if condition in `ng-if` fails...

```
<div ng-if="user.image">
  <img src="assets/abc.jpg">
</div>
```

So Image is loaded if user.image is false.

We want that image to load only if user.image is true.

**Edit** Actually image does not show on UI but in chrome developer tools in Network it is loaded.

Comment: Then either your `user.image` isn't falsy or you use angular 1.2 or lower. Any console errors?

Comment: We use angular 1.2.28

Comment: Ok so we use Angular 1.4 then our problem solves ?

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken, it wasn't about `ng-if` that wasnt in 1.2

Comment: No still image loaded , Actually image does not show on UI . But it is loaded in network chrome developer tools

Comment: Issue was solve by using ng-src instead of src

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ng-if` is in 1.2.  Use `ng-src` in the `IMG` tag instead of `src` to prevent the browser from loading the image first thing before Angular gets a chance to compile the HTML.

```
<div ng-if="user.image">
  <img ng-src="assets/abc.jpg">
</div>
```

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/directive/ngSrc